# GIT: есть ли незапушенные комиты?

Tags: git

Как узнать, если ли комиты, которые незапушены ?через гит лог непонятно.
Чтобы лишний раз git push не писать.

Comment: Т.е. написать лишний раз команду, чтобы узнать, есть ли незапушенные коммиты - ок, а написать git push - лениво?

Comment: Вы думаете, что git - это одна-две команды и все? Ой, как вы ошибаетесь, git - это минимум десяток постоянных команд с разными ключами и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

```
git status
```

Выдаст что-то вроде:

```
Ваша ветка опережает «origin/master» на 1 коммит.
```

Само собой, для того, чтобы это работало, внешний репозиторий должен быть обновлён `git fetch` (или `git pull`).

Answer (score 1):

Если требуется посмотреть визуально, то можно использовать Tortoisegit. В нем есть команда  Show log, которая показывает все коммиты и в локальном, и в удалённом репозитории. Специальные метки показывают текущие коммиты.

Answer (score 0):

```
git log @{u}..
```

Ещё `git status` пишет в самом верху.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй: `git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s"`


ca82a6d - Scott Chacon, 6 years ago : changed the version number

085bb3b - Scott Chacon, 6 years ago : removed unnecessary test

a11bef0 - Scott Chacon, 6 years ago : first commit

---

Или: `git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" --graph`

* 2d3acf9 ignore errors from SIGCHLD on trap

*  5e3ee11 Merge branch 'master' of git://github.com/...

|\

| * 420eac9 Added a method for getting the current branch.

* | 30e367c timeout code and tests

* | 5a09431 add timeout protection to grit

* | e1193f8 support for heads with slashes in them

|/

*d6016bc require time for xmlschema

---

Но лучше используй `git push`, тк это более правильно.Ведь ты должен знать, что творится у тебя в репозитории

Глянь тут все теги к **git log**  [**Клац**](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)